# getting /src/components/App.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "}" error with onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-hooks

I have the following code for a button that is in a small React form / project.

```
<button onClick={()=>resetName();resetSurname();resetEmail()}>Submit</button>
```

The reset function is based on a hook that I created which is the following:
import { useState } from "react";

```
export default initialValue => {
  const [name, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setValue("");
  };
  return [name, reset, handleChange];
};
```

I have imported this into my App.js file.  Which reads as follows:
import React from "react";

```
import useInputHook from "../Hooks/useFormState";
function App() {
  const [name, resetName, setName] = useInputHook("");
  const [surname, resetSurname, setSurname] = useInputHook("");
  const [email, resetEmail, setEmail] = useInputHook("");
```

Basically the ultimate goal is to reset the fields of the form.  Should this be done this way or am I going about this the wrong way?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Arrow functions expect a single expression; you’re calling multiple functions, so they need to be in a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use brackets if you are calling more than one function.

Replace:

```
<button onClick={()=>resetName();resetSurname();resetEmail()}>Submit</button>
```

With:

```
<button
  onClick={()=>{
    resetName();
    resetSurname();
    resetEmail();
  }}
>
  Submit
</button>
```

> Unexpected token, expected “}” error with onClick event

Now React expects `}` after `resetName();`.

Comment: Cheers Dave and Deykun.